# How to download a file on Client side using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

I am pretty new to nodejs basically I am trying to send a file saved on my laptop to the client to download.The file is saved in the same folder as app.js(filename of nodejs file).When I am executing this code it is giving 
TypeError: res.download is not a function.
Please suggest a way so that I can implement this.
PS: I have also tried writing res.download('/filtered_database.csv'); but same error is coming up.

**Nodejs code:**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express')
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body);
        const express = require('express')
const {spawn} = require('child_process');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {

 var dataToSend;
 // spawn new child process to call the python script
 //console.log('Start')
 const python = spawn("python", ["filter.py",body]);
 // collect data from script
 python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
  dataToSend = data.toString();
 });

 // in close event we are sure that stream from child process is closed
 python.on('close', (code) => {
 console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
 // send data to browser
 res.send(dataToSend)
 });

})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
res.writeHead(301,
    { Location: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' }
  );
  res.download(__dirname + 'filtered_database.csv', 'filtered_database.csv');
  //res.attachment('filtered_database.csv');
  res.end();
    });
}
    else {
      res.end(`
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
          }

        body {
            background-image: url('https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/38/26/KlxIwM.jpg');
            height: 100%; 

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
                    }
        </style>    
          <center>
          <h3>WELCOME TO THE POSTCODE MAPPING TOOL</h3>

            <form action="/" method="post">
            <label>Enter Country</label><input type="text" name="Country" /><br />
            <label>Enter City  </label><input type="text" name="City" /><br />
            <label>Enter State  </label><input type="text" name="State" /><br />
                <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000">
                <button>Generate CSV file</button>
                </a>

            </form>
            </center>
        </body>
        </html>
      `);
    }
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const http = require('http'),
  fileSystem = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/filtered_database.csv');
    const stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    const readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
    readStream.pipe(response);
})
.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I tried this but again the file does not start to download

Comment: Is your client a web page? Can you show the client code